# How to create a dataset for CNN from Mri Nifti files?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-datasets, faster-rcnn

I have data in nifti format, these are 3 axial images of an animal’s brain, how to create a dataset for training a convolutional neural network, for segmenting brain regions, by python 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nibabel` library for loading `nifti` files using `nibabel.load(path)`. And from that, you can get numpy array and combine all arrays to form a dataset in numpy arrays or convert it to `H5py` format as your choice.

Comment: Yap, but how right make a labels and masks for pattern recognition